# Nested modules lazy loading angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

In my project, I have below module hierarchy.

[image]

And I have **shared module** which will be shared between **Module A** and all its children.

Q: Do I have to import **shared module** in every child module of **Module A** or importing it in **Module A** is enough?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to import SharedModule in every module (and child module) of Module A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import it in **each** child module separately, if that module will use at least one item from the **Shared** module.

That being said, you should consider **not** having Shared module at all, since it's a bad practice. Imagine you have 20 items in your Shared module, and some of you child modules will use only one item from it. Well, you will have to import the whole Shared module (even you will use only one item from it), which will increase the final bundle for your child module and decrease the performance.

Comment: are you sure its bad practice? tree shaking should remove unused components, and the modular architecture of Angular should ensure that each module is defined once, no matter how many times its imported.